# Opencv CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT return negative large number with h264 video

Tags: python, opencv

I have two identical videos. One is "video.h264" the other one is "video.avi"

When I do this

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fn)

if not cap.isOpened(): 
    print("could not open :",fn)
    exit
    
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
width  = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps    = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

print("Length is ",length," Widht and Height (",width,",",height,") FPS ",fps)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fn)
property_id = int(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) 
length = int(cv2.VideoCapture.get(cap, property_id))
print( length )
```

If fn is the avi file I get

```
Length is  600  Widht and Height ( 3840 , 1920 ) FPS  10.0
600
```

But with the h264 file I get

```
Length is  -76861433640456  Widht and Height ( 3840 , 1920 ) FPS  10.0
-76861433640456
```

As you can see the length is a very large negative number. Why this could be happening? Is this a matter of typing?

Comment: `.h264` extension applies raw H.264 video stream. Raw H.264 video stream doesn't store the total number of frames as "metadata". For getting the frame count of `.h264` file, we have to iterate the entire file, and count all the frames (OpenCV is not the best tool for counting video frames). Negative number probably marks "unsuccessful" status. Are the two files really identical (`video.h264` is an AVI file with `h264` extension)?

Comment: This format supports 4K and up to 8K Ultra High-Definition. Through this compression, the codec is able to maintain the same video quality despite using only half of the storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you `h264` video is corrupted somehow. You can fix this by re-encoding the video (e.g. with ffmpeg):

```bash
ffmpeg -i /path/to/you/video.h264 -vf fps=30 -vcodec libx264 /path/to/you/video_reencoded.h264
```